# Convert an array of string into new string in VBA

Tags: string, vba, excel

I tried to create a VBA code that convert a string (in an array) to a new string (which also in an array). However, i'm getting a problem with those original strings that almost identical. E.g. "Power Partner", "Power Partner OEM".

Is there any way I can convert them accurately? Thanks!

```
Private Function cvrt(orig As Variant) As Variant

    Dim orgVal As Variant, newVal As Variant, i As Integer

    cvrt = orig

    orgVal = Array("Central", "Clarke", "Power Partner", "Power Partner OEM")
    newVal = Array("Central Data", "Clarke Data", "Onsite Power Partner", "Onsite Energy OEM")

    For i = 0 To 3
        cvrt = Replace(cvrt, orgVal(i), newVal(i), vbTextCompare)
    Next i

End Function
```

Comment: What problem are you getting? What is the value of `orig` that you are passing to the function?

Comment: I'm getting a problem with the last two strings in my code as they are almost identical. When I execute the code, the result for "Power Partner OEM" is incorrect, it became "Onsite Onsite Energy OEM"

Comment: What is the value of `orig` that you are passing to the function?

Comment: the value of `orig` came from a range, which is technically listed in the `orgVal`

Comment: Aha! I didn't see you already accepted an answer. I was testing the code. Anyways, I still posted it for future visitors :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to enter the complex world of regular expressions,

- do it in 2 phases using an intermediate replacement
- Follow the rule of putting the "largest strings first" in the original array. Hence `Power Partner OEM` should come *before* `Power Partner`.

.

```
Private Function cvrt(orig As Variant) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, orgVal, newVal, interm
    cvrt = orig
    orgVal = Array("Power Partner OEM", "Power Partner", "Central", "Clarke")
    interm = Array("xxx0", "xxx1", "xxx2", "xxx3")
    newVal = Array("Onsite Energy OEM", "Onsite Power Partner", "Central Data", "Clarke Data")
   For i = 0 To 3
       cvrt = Replace(cvrt, orgVal(i), interm(i), vbTextCompare)
   Next i
   For i = 0 To 3
       cvrt = Replace(cvrt, interm(i), newVal(i), vbTextCompare)
   Next i
End Function
```

Notice the intermediate array is not necessary, you can use `"xxx" & i` everywhere instead of `interm(i)`...

Answer (score 1):

> I'm getting a problem with the last two strings in my code as they are almost identical. When I execute the code, the result for "Power Partner OEM" is incorrect, it became "Onsite Onsite Energy OEM" – kulapo
>
> the value of orig came from a range, which is technically listed in the orgVal – kulapo

The most simplest way to do it is not to use `Variants` and use `Range` and then use the inbuilt `Range.replace` with `xlWhole` to avoid false positive matches.

```
Private Function cvrt(orig As Range) As Range '<~~~~~
    Dim orgVal As Variant, newVal As Variant, i As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = orig
    
    orgVal = Array("Central", "Clarke", "Power Partner", "Power Partner OEM")
    newVal = Array("Central Data", "Clarke Data", "Onsite Power Partner", "Onsite Energy OEM")

    For i = 0 To 3
        rng.Replace What:=orgVal(i), Replacement:=newVal(i), LookAt:=xlWhole
    Next i
    
    Set orig = rng
End Function
```

Screenshot

[image]

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim r As Range
    
    Set r = cvrt(Range("A1:A4"))
End Sub


Private Function cvrt(orig As Range) As Range
    Dim orgVal As Variant, newVal As Variant, i As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = orig
    
    orgVal = Array("Central", "Clarke", "Power Partner", "Power Partner OEM")
    newVal = Array("Central Data", "Clarke Data", "Onsite Power Partner", "Onsite Energy OEM")

    For i = 0 To 3
        rng.Replace What:=orgVal(i), Replacement:=newVal(i), LookAt:=xlWhole
    Next i
    
    Set orig = rng
End Function
```

Comment: I will also try this way because of its simplicity. Thanks @SiddharthRout!